# Textbook probability question - is this unrelated data to throw you off?

Tags: probability, discrete-distributions

4.24 from Newbold 8th Edition:

> The probability of a team winning a game is 0.45. What is the probability that the team will:
>   a) win 2 games out of 5; 
>   b) win 10 games out of 25?

If the probability of winning a game, any game, at any time, is 0.45, and if we consider games independent events, then winning 2 games is 0.45*0.45 out of however many; and winning 10 games is 0.45^10.

Or is the idea that for 2 out of 5 games it's 1/5*1/4 and for 10 out of 25 games it's 1/25*1/24... etc? In which case what is the 0.45 doing in all this?

Comment: This sounds like it is a self-study question. Please look at [this information about self-study questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), add the `self-study` tag to the question, and say a bit more if possible about where you are stuck. Note, for example, that in your first suggested answer what you are looking at is winning N games _without losing one_. Think instead about how many ways you might be able to have five games total and win exactly two out of five.

Comment: @EdM, thanks for the comment, I didn't know about the self-study tag. Also thanks for the comment about 'N games without losing', I hadn't realised that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as the number of games increases, the number of games that you win is expected to increase as well because you get more chances.

For example, let's say we want to find the probability of winning $2$ games out of $3$ games. The possible situations are $WWL,WLW,LWW$, where $L$ denotes losing and $W$ denotes winning.

The probability of the first situation is $$P(WWL)=P(W)P(W)P(L)=0.45\times0.45\times0.55$$

Similarly, you can find $P(WLW),P(LWW)$, and sum them to get the final answer. And, you can then generalise this idea to answer your questions.

Note also that these can be answered using [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) as well.

Comment: Thanks, @gunes, I understand it now, I'll "play it out". (And yes, the exercise is in a chapter titled 'Discrete Probability Distributions' - but before the section called 'Binomial Distributions' ...).

Comment: can I get back to "the probability of winning 2 games out of 5 is less than winning 2 games out of 10." , please? At 0.45 probability of winning 2 out of 5 is .337 while 2 out of 10 is only .076 ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: good catch, it's *more* than.

Comment: Oh! :-D I spent about an hour this afternoon with a TI-83+ and books to try to figure it out! :)))))

Comment: It never hurts to spend time thinking. :D Thank you for always helping me here. :)

Comment: "So, the probability of winning 2 games out of 5 is more than winning 2 games out of 10." is only true for some values of the win probability: if the chance of winning is low (specifically, less than $1 - (10/45)^{1/5} \approx 0.26$), you are more likely to win 2/10 than 2/5.

Comment: @Mark Right, it wasn't a rigorous statement anyway. Removed it.